# Strange memory behaviour for struct ivar in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, c, struct, libxml2

I'm using [Ben Reeves' HTML parser](https://github.com/zootreeves/Objective-C-HMTL-Parser) to parse text with some HTML tags. It represents every node as an HTMLNode object, which has only one ivar of type xmlNode* from libxml2. xmlNode is a struct that looks like this:

```
struct _xmlNode {
void           *_private;   /* application data */
xmlElementType   type;  /* type number, must be second ! */
const xmlChar   *name;      /* the name of the node, or the entity */
struct _xmlNode *children;  /* parent->childs link */
struct _xmlNode *last;  /* last child link */
struct _xmlNode *parent;    /* child->parent link */
struct _xmlNode *next;  /* next sibling link  */
struct _xmlNode *prev;  /* previous sibling link  */
struct _xmlDoc  *doc;   /* the containing document */

/* End of common part */
xmlNs           *ns;        /* pointer to the associated namespace */
xmlChar         *content;   /* the content */
struct _xmlAttr *properties;/* properties list */
xmlNs           *nsDef;     /* namespace definitions on this node */
void            *psvi;  /* for type/PSVI informations */
unsigned short   line;  /* line number */
unsigned short   extra; /* extra data for XPath/XSLT */
```

};

I have method which takes a string, wraps it into an HTMLNode and returns that node:

```
- (HTMLNode*)nodeFromString:(NSString*)string 
{
    /* Creates parser which wraps string in <doc><html><body> tags */

    HTMLParser *parser = [[HTMLParser alloc] initWithString:string error:nil];

    /* Get contents of <body> tag and return it to parse later */

    HTMLNode *body = [parser body];    
    return body;
}
```

Using this HTMLNode inside this method is fine. But if I try to use this node in some other place in code I get really weird results. Most variables inside xmlNode structure point to some random places in memory.

Here's how debug output for HTMLNode looks like inside nodeFromString method:

```
body    HTMLNode *  0x7faaf96a3240  0x00007faaf96a3240
_node   xmlNode *   0x7faaf96b7ec0  0x00007faaf96b7ec0
    _private    void *  NULL    0x0000000000000000
    type    xmlElementType  XML_ELEMENT_NODE    XML_ELEMENT_NODE
    name    const xmlChar * "body"  0x00007faaf9693df0
    children    _xmlNode *  0x7faaf96b7fd0  0x00007faaf96b7fd0
        _private    void *  NULL    0x0000000000000000
        type    xmlElementType  XML_ELEMENT_NODE    XML_ELEMENT_NODE
        name    const xmlChar * "p" 0x00007faaf9678470
        children    _xmlNode *  0x7faaf96b80e0  0x00007faaf96b80e0
            _private    void *  NULL    0x0000000000000000
            type    xmlElementType  XML_TEXT_NODE   XML_TEXT_NODE
            name    const xmlChar * "text"  0x0000000100e31304
            children    _xmlNode *  NULL    0x0000000000000000
            content xmlChar *   "My content string" 0x00007faafa910200
```

And this is debug output for the same HTMLNode object returned from this method and used elsewhere:

```
body    HTMLNode *  0x7faaf96a3240  0x00007faaf96a3240
_node   xmlNode *   0x7faaf96b7ec0  0x00007faaf96b7ec0
    _private    void *  0x900007faaf96b7db  0x900007faaf96b7db
    type    xmlElementType  -1349076995 -1349076995
    name    const xmlChar * 0x7faaf969000a  0x00007faaf969000a
    children    _xmlNode *  0x7faaf96b7fd0  0x00007faaf96b7fd0
        _private    void *  0x600007faaf96b7ec  0x600007faaf96b7ec
        type    xmlElementType  -1349076978 -1349076978
        name    const xmlChar * ""  0x00007faaf967000a
        children    _xmlNode *  0x7faaf96b80e0  0x00007faaf96b80e0
            _private    void *  0x700007faaf96b7fd  0x700007faaf96b7fd
            type    xmlElementType  -1349076961 -1349076961
            name    const xmlChar * "XPathEvalExpression: %d object left on the stack\n"    0x0000000100e3000a
            children    _xmlNode *  NULL    0x0000000000000000
            content xmlChar *   "My content string" 0x00007faafa910200
```

Why memory of xmlNode ivar is damaged? What should I do to prevent it (I really don't want to parse entire string inside one method)?

Simple sample project to reproduce this issue can be found [here](https://github.com/serkrapiv/SKHTMLParserBrokenExample).

Comment: I think it's parser's bug. Xml hierarchy is deallocated with `HTMLParser` object.

Comment: Damn, I wasted hours and didn't even think about that parser object. Indeed it is deallocated with parser :(

Comment: @Cy-4AH I'll accept this if you post is as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's parser's bug. Xml hierarchy is deallocated with HTMLParser object.